# Is there a way to "broaden" True values of a vector in R?

Tags: r

I have a vector of logical values among which only a few are True, and I would like to transform this vector so the two values on each side of a TRUE would become TRUE too.

So in other word I would like to transform a vector like that:

`...FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE...`

so the two FALSE around each TRUE value become TRUE too, so that the final vector looks like:

`...FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE...`

Here is a real example of what I'd like to change:

```
[20] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[39] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[58] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE 
[77] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[96]  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: something like `x[c(which(x) - 1, which(x) + 1)] <- TRUE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
examp <- replace(rep(FALSE, 10), c(3, 8), TRUE)
examp
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Base R:

```
replace(examp, c(outer(c(1, -1), which(examp), '+')), TRUE)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Using `data.table::shift`:

```
Reduce('|', data.table::shift(examp, -1:1, fill = FALSE))
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like mentioned in the comment, but as I understand you want two values around the `TRUE` value to be also converted to `TRUE`. So you simply could do it twice.

My suggestion would be operating with the *lag* and *lead* versions of the vector and an *or* operation:

```r
v = c(
    F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, T, F, T,
    F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, T, T, F, F,
    F, F, F, F, F, F, F, T, T, F, F, F, F, T, T, T, T, F, F, 
    F, F, F, F, F, T, T, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, T, T,
    T, T
)

l = length(v)

v = v | c(v[-1], F) | c(F, v[-l])
v = v | c(v[-1], F) | c(F, v[-l])
```